# Add groups to co-owner role and as viewer-uploader to collaboration via box api

Tags: box-api

We would like to utilize box to store documents for our corporate collaboration app.

As such, our application has 2 roles for each space:  admins and members

The idea is to:

- create a folder for each space under a generic account in box owned by the application
- create a corresponding set of box groups (ourapp-spacename-admins and ourapp-spacename-members)
- assign the -admins group as co-owners of folder
- assign the -members group as viewer/uploaders

From that point on, the only op needed is to manage changes to the groups.

It seems all of this is doable via the API except for assigning the proper roles to the groups.  From what I can
tell, the API only allows individuals to added to collab roles.  Is this the case?  is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of late last week, Box has APIs to let you collaborate a group onto a folder

You do it the same way you collaborate a user onto a folder

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/collaborations \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-d '{"item": { "id": "FOLDER_ID", "type": "folder"}, "accessible_by": { "id": "GROUP_ID"}, "role": "editor"}' \
-X POST
```

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't a capability for interacting with Groups in the V2 API, unfortunately; however,  we're planning on adding it sometime in the coming months.